# Add cross-page text referenced to text

Tags: header-footer, appendices

I have `\appendix` in my document and I want to have referenced text throud pages for current section. For example:
[image: example of document]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please tell use which class you are using, because this can affect `\appendix`. At best add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your basic usage. -- I removed the `xetex` tag because your question is not XeTeX specific.

Comment: Thanks @MartinScharrer;) It's doesn't depends on \appendix, I can have such pages without it, I only just need functionality.

Comment: Please consider being a bit more specific about what you need to accomplish. Are you maybe looking to place the *name* of the section -- "Some Appendix", for instance -- in the upper-right hand side of the running header of the page? If so, do check out the `fancyhdr` package and its capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle you can add a text at the top of the next page(s) using `\afterpage` from the `afterpage` package. You should define a macro which `\afterpage`-s itself but is reset when you don't need it any longer.

Here some principle code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument

\appendix
\chapter{SOME APPENDIX}
\newcommand\mycontinue{\noindent\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\textbf{Continue SOME APPENDIX}}\afterpage{\mycontinue}}
\afterpage{\mycontinue}
\Blindtext \Blindtext \Blindtext
\Blindtext \Blindtext \Blindtext
\let\mycontinue\relax % disable text

\chapter{Other stuff}
other text \Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You a lot, that's amazing, but there is issue. When I use \lstinputlisting it's create one blank page, and on other page is two of "Continue SOME APPENDIX".
*****************code example*******
\section*{SOME APPENDIX}
\subsection*{some text}
\lstinputlisting[language=Java]{code/Worker.java}