# empty page afterpage listings

Tags: listings, page-breaking, afterpage

I get an emptypage on multi page `listings` if I use listings with `afterpage`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{%
%some fancy stuff
}
\begin{lstlisting}
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123

\end{lstlisting}



\end{document}
```

I think this question is different to
[\afterpage issue with \lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54340/afterpage-issue-with-lstlisting)
because there was a recursive macro definition, causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Er well it must be a feature of `listings` because clearly it can't be anything wrong with `afterpage`.

You can get them to agree on the page break by boxing and unboxing the listing.

```
\setbox0\vbox{
\begin{lstlisting}

...
\end{lstlisting}
}
\unvbox0
```

Comment: I don't think this is a "feature". Anyway I was trying the following as workaround:
`\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\setbox0\vbox\bgroup}
\AtEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\egroup\unvbox0}`
but it isn't working. Any Idea?

Comment: does it work on your real example if you use the setbox directly and just fail with AtBeginEnvironment, or does it not work at all?

Comment: It works in the real example and just fails with `AtBeginEnvironment`

Comment: someone who knows etoolbox might be able to help (I've never used it) the timing of the end code is a bit tricky in verbatim-like environments.

Comment: ok thx, I don't need to use etoolbox, just would like to "patch" `lstlisting` ;)