# etoolbox patch lstlistings

Tags: listings, etoolbox, afterpage

This is a follow up question to [empty page afterpage listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78794/empty-page-afterpage-listings/78800).

I'm trying to work around a listings problem with etoolbox:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\setbox0\vbox\bgroup}
\AtEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\egroup\unvbox0}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{
%something
}

\begin{lstlisting}
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

But I get `Missing } inserted \end{lstlisting}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `\BeforeBeginEnvironment`, and `\AfterEndEnvironment` instead:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\setbox0\vbox\bgroup}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\egroup\unvbox0}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{
%something
}

\begin{lstlisting}
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
    asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123 asd 123
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: works great, I must have missed this in the documentation.